# How to pass/inject a session-specific info to the below level?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-rest

I have a rest controller and I want to give means to access to a "Session" bean that I create by extracting the infos from the http header.

For this reason I created an HttpInterceptor that pre-handles the request by extracting the headers:

```
@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
        throws Exception {

    String remoteUser = request.getHeader("x-remote-user");
    log.info("Helo {}", remoteUser);
    MySession session = new MySession();
    session.setUser(remoteUser);

    //what now?

    return true;
}
```

But, how can I do something like this:

```
public MyController {

     public ResponseEntitity<String> action(Request a){
           MySession user = getUserSession(); //here I should be able to retrieve the session for that specific user
     }
 }
```

Comment: did you try `HttpServletRequest` method call `request.getSession().setAttribute("key", "value") and then access it by `request.getSession.getAttribute` ?

Comment: I wanted to try something that was not so explicit as use directly the session